# Can't download and save srt file using DownloadFile

Tags: vb.net

I want to download a srt (subtitles) file from subtitles4free.net but I can't understand how I am supposed to do it.

I tried downloading it using

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("http://www.getsubtitle.com/webService/download_subtitle.php?cod_bsplayer=38187011&post_date=11-06-2015", "C:\Users\User1\Downloads\subs.srt")
```

but the file that gets downloaded is a srt file containing some weird text, probably because it has to be a direct download url with a file extension. Is there any way to get this to work and if not, is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Already did that. Same result.

Comment: the url is not on subtitiles4free.net. what are you doing?

Comment: Actually, I grab the url from subtitles4free.net. The url is on getsubtitle.com.

Comment: the file format is a zip, not srt. no wonder you get wierd text

Comment: Hahaha true. Didn't notice that. I tried saving it as a zip and it worked fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file format you are downloading is `ZIP`, not `SRT`. Save it as a .zip file. Extract it and you'll get the .srt file.